# tr and while/until commands in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, tr

What I am doing is to encode a character 13 places from its current location.
For example, if I input welcome, it should echo jrypbzr.

this is what I wrote:

```
read words

echo $words | tr '[A-Za-z]' '[????]' (Please ignore the ???? part.)
```

This successfully solved the encoding problem, however, I need to input multiple times and the code I wrote only read one time. Can someone tell me how to input multiple times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, have your input in a text file. Then

```
while read words
do

  # here, do whatever you want with words

done < your-input-file.txt
```

Explanation: you feed contents of the input file to the while loop, which reads it line by line and stores in words.

If you want to use a delimiter other than newline, you can use:

```
while IFS=";" read words
```

and place within the IFS= " " whatever delimiter you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe!
I have one more question here,
how can I make the shell script to exit the user inputting by entering an empty line?

Comment: if [ "$words" -eq "" ] then break